# Python combobox value: if x=y then x=z

Tags: python, combobox, sap-gui

I would like to ask for help in that if you select one of the options in the combox, then you will get another value back.

This is my code:

```
vlist = ["FGT1", "FGT2", "FGT3", "FGT4", "FGT5","FGT6"]

ses = ttk.Combobox(master, values = vlist, width=25)
ses.state(['readonly'])

if ses.get() == "FGT1":
        ses="0"
elif ses.get() == "FGT2":
        ses="1"
elif ses.get() == "FGT3":
       ses="2"
elif ses.get() == "FGT4":
        ses="3"
elif ses.get() == "FGT5":
       ses="4"
elif ses.get() == "FGT6":
       ses="5"

def sap():
    
    SapGui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine
    session5 = SapGui.FindById("ses["+ses.get()+"]")
```

So if I select FGT1 then enter 1 for `ses.get()` not `FGT1`

I tried `sestwo="0"` after the if. and `FindById("ses["+sestwo+"]")`. But it's not working.

Comment: Is the question about `ses.get()` for `Combobox`, or about `FindById`? If it's for the two, please ask 2 distinct questions. For information, concerning `SapGui.FindById("ses[...]")`, it's all wrong, so maybe after you have solved your issue about the `ComboBox`, you'd like to ask a separate question with tag `sap-gui`.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of text variable and get the value from the text variable.

```
combo_var = StringVar()
ses = ttk.Combobox(master,values=vlist,textvariable=combo_var)
```

Get the values using variable.

```
if combo_var.get() == 'FGT1':
    ses = "0"
```

About StringVar()

A variable defined using StringVar() holds a string data where we can set text value and can retrieve it. Also, we can pass this variable to textvariable parameter for a widget like Entry. The widget will automatically get updated with the new value whenever the value of the StringVar() variable changes.